# Having a Castle before they are invented?

Tags: technological-development, architecture, ancient-history

Amid a [Sword and Sandal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SwordAndSandal) era, my protagonist comes from an ancient and powerful family who has lived in a castle for many generations. The problem is that castles shouldn't exist yet, at least not for humans. The protagonist's family is elven and humans and elves seldom interact at this point in history. BUT, this particular family oversees a [village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Settlement_hierarchy) of humans that are something like [serfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom) (but they are allowed to leave for certain reasons like trade).

Supposing that the castle is of elvish origin then, and supposing that magic exists, what would prevent humans from learning from and replicating this "new" architectural technology for themselves? Humans shouldn't start implementing this sort of architecture for another few/several hundred years and keep in mind that the castle has already existed for thousands of years without being replicated by humans.

Comment: TBH I feel like the real questions are A: What would the humans even want a castle for in the first place, and B: Why would the elves even ALLOW the humans to build their own castle without going over there, killing them all, and dumping their castle in the swamp?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91848/discussion-on-question-by-justsnilloc-having-a-castle-before-they-are-invented).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the technology to have swords, you have the technology to have something like a castle. Consider wooden [motte-and-bailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motte-and-bailey_castle) castles. They simply take lots and lots of people who haul earth and logs.

But imagine the elvish castles have cyclopean walls with [large blocks](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sacsahuaman_Tiopunco.jpg). They were done in ancient times, when the elves

- had magic
- were helped by astronauts
- enslaved lots and lots of humans

(pick one). Human warlords and sorcerors may try to copy elvish castles, but they invariably fall short.

Comment: Comments usually aren’t meant to explain selected answers, but I feel there is something to add by doing so here. If humans have a reference and the tools/materials available to them to make something, then why can’t they make it? They lack in other ways. Their resources (be it laborers, materials, knowledge, etc.) lack the quantitative or qualitative requirements and that’s why. It’s a simple, but very reasonable answer.

Answer (score 12):

A castle is a lot more than seeing one and copying it. I see cars everyday, but wouldn't be able to make one. I couldn't even make the tools that make a carburetor, and I'm an engineer. Same with castles, there is a whole bunch of technology behind castles ranging from tools, to stone/woodworking, to quarrying and transporting materials, to strategic positioning etc,. they're a culmination of centuries of technological inventions in multiple fields. Just making a hammer from scratch needs several inventions.

If the humans never saw one built, had no access to the tools, and didn't understand how it all fits together,they couldn't make one.

Comment: Depends on the castle, most early castles are little more and shaped earth and log walls.

Comment: _"Just making a hammer from scratch needs several inventions"_ just one actually, the invention of _hitting things with a big rock_, it was one of our earlier efforts in the field of invention actually :)

Comment: @pelinore. That's not a hammer, that's a stone. You need to find a way to affix a handle before you can call it a hammer.

Comment: If you can use it to hammer something it's a hammer, for at least as long as you use it so.. simples :)

Comment: Smashing something with a rock gives you a _lot_ less mechanical advantage (and opportunity to build momentum) than rotating a lever that happens to have a sturdy heavy thing at the other end.

Comment: @JesseAmano it might but a hammer without a handle is still a hammer & (as I already pointed out here) that's something that only needs the invention of just _**one**_ not _"several"_ concepts as asserted by Kilisi, & an "invention" at that which we've actually had since time immemorial, almost certainly since before we were _**us**_ in fact, after all, even sea otters use hammers & "anvils" so I can't imagine that even our pre-hominid & even pre-ape ancestors didn't have them, a hammer is practically something that never actually _**needed**_ inventing.

Comment: @Pelinore I strongly disagree. This discussion is in the context of _carpentry_, so although abstractly I would only weakly disagree with your implied definition of "hammer = any hard object that can be grasped", in **this case** the implied definition has to be one that can satisfy the use case "apply concentrated blunt force in a specific direction" which requites that you have at least a basic understanding of how mass, velocity, angular momentum, and force work. You obviously don't need the exact Newtonian equations, but you've got to at least know the concepts.

Comment: Plus, even once you understand that you need a sturdy but light handle attached to a dense but small and manageable head with a blunt side, there's still a challenge in shaping the handle, shaping the head (which ideally would be made of a very different material that requires a different shaping technique), and connecting them together. Early hammer-like tools were sometimes put together with knots and sometimes with adhesives[citations needed]; both were arguably "inventions" all on their own, and both had their downsides in practical use.

Comment: @JesseAmano fair enough then, but a hammer with a handle still only needs the invention of two concepts (or at most three) rather than Kilisi's _"several"_, it just needs the concept of bashing one object with another & the concept of a lever (and _perhaps_ that of tying one thing to another) :) most of the rest (mass velocity angle shaping smoothing etc) are more matters of fine tuning (by trial error & experience) skill than inventions & all understood very early by any pre-human ancestor that could knap flint & fix flint heads to spears.

Comment: Just to establish the threshold for the "basic understanding of how mass, velocity, angular momentum, and force work."  that is necessary to invent a hammer: 
 https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2015/04/video-clever-monkeys-adjust-how-hard-they-hammer-nuts  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Cp7_In7f88

Comment: A hammer stone used that was used in making Flint  tools by our ancestors may be less optimal than a hammer with a handle would have been, but it was still a technology that worked well enough for the task at hand.

Comment: @JohnDvorak But what if it is a *long* stone?

Comment: @Chronocidal then it's a rock baton. Most likely unsuitable for use as a hammer.

Comment: @Pelinore I meant a metal headed hammer, requires knowledge of metallurgy, forging, crafting a handle of the appropriate strength, fastening the head to the handle in such a way that it won't detach or break. Hammers need to take a lot of punishment.

Comment: @Kilisi  _"meant a metal headed hammer, requires knowledge of metallurgy, forging, crafting a handle of the appropriate strength, fastening the head to the handle.."_ I'm sorry but if that's so then then your reference to hammers is even more meaningless to the OP's question than I'd thought ~ a metal headed hammer with a handle is (or at least can be) utterly irrelevant to an ability with masonry & the ability to build with stone, we were doing those things long before we had metal of any description at all.

Comment: @Pelinore suit yourself ~shrugs~ .... I also made a reference to a carburetor.... not saying it's integral to building a castle

Answer (score 6):

Consider **Orthanc**.

[image: orthanc]

From the Two Towers

> There stood a tower of marvelous shape. It was fashioned by the
>   builders of old, who smoothed the Ring of Isengard, and yet it seemed
>   a thing not made by the craft of Men, but riven from the bones of the
>   earth in the ancient torment of the hills...
>
> They came now to the foot of Orthanc. It was black, and the rock
>   gleamed as if it were wet. The many faces of the stone had sharp edges
>   as though they had been newly chiselled. A few scorings, and small
>   flake-like splinters near the base, were all the marks that it bore of
>   the fury of the Ents.

The elf castle is not a glorified hut, or pile of stone.  It is altogether different, and so foreign from the things humans make for themselves that the humans view it more like a mountain, or the moon, or perhaps the Wall in Game of Thrones  - an awesome artifact made by the Creator or ancient race of giants, but beyond what human skill can reproduce.  I like how Tolkien describes it as "riven from the bones of the earth" - not the way humans make buildings.

An interesting thing about Orthanc is that it was viewed exactly that way by every being which occupied Middle Earth at that time.  It was alien even to Saruman.

This is how it is for your elves.  The castle they live in was not made by them either, but predates the elves also.  It could be one of the "cyclopean ruins" one finds in Lovecraft stories - build to last by an ancient race.  The other reason the humans don't copy it is that they find it an uncomfortable thing to look at.  The elves don't particularly like the looks of their castle either but they are tough minded, unsuperstitious and they do appreciate the practical benefits it affords.

Comment: I kind of like the basic concept. Something like concrete would be good enough I think. For example, seeing the Colosseum or the Pantheon would help you exactly not at all trying to copy them because Roman concrete is not a natural substance you can find, it has to be manufactured from things that do not resemble it that much. My examples also have arches that would be hard to copy unless you actually understand the principles behind them.

Comment: Bricks are another technology that cannot be copied. Even if you have ceramics and understand how to make them, making enough for a large building **requires** economy on par with the Roman Empire or Renaissance Italy. You just cannot afford the logistics otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Make it a **natural fortress**

If you want to have a castle before castles became a thing, turn to mother nature.
In a sword-and-sandal world people can build houses, walls, etc., yet if your castle consists of a very-defensible natural feature, then your castle is impossible to copy.

See e.g. Massada

[image]